# Extract nested hash facts from puppet's facter command-line tool. How?

Tags: puppet, facter

This might be obvious. However, after searching through facter's help, puppetlab's website, and Google I am still unable to figure out how to retrieve a nested facter fact .

For example, I can do:

`>facter os`

`{"release"=>{"major"=>"6", "minor"=>"7", "full"=>"6.7"}, "family"=>"RedHat", "name"=>"CentOS"}`

How do I retrieve `os['name']` or `os['release']['minor']` or any arbitrary nested fact via command line with facter?

Answer (score 3):

Nested fact values can be viewed in the CLI by using a dot between variables

e.g. to retrieve `os['release']['minor']` in the CLI type:
`facter os.release.minor`

**EDIT:**
Apperently this only works with facter 3.x.

This doc gives a brief mention on how to access these structured (aka nested) facts (http://docs.puppetlabs.com/facter/3.1/core_facts.html):

> Legacy Facts Note: As of Facter 3, legacy facts such as architecture
>   are hidden by default to reduce noise in Facter’s default command-line
>   output. These older facts are now part of more useful structured
>   facts; for example, architecture is now part of the os fact and
>   accessible as os.architecture. You can still use these legacy facts in
>   Puppet manifests ($architecture), request them on the command line
>   (facter architecture), and view them alongside structured facts
>   (facter --show-legacy).

Unfortunately I cannot find information about accessing nested facts using older versions.

In facter v3 you can do the following:

```
facter os
{
  architecture => "amd64",
  distro => {
    codename => "trusty",
    description => "Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS",
    id => "Ubuntu",
    release => {
      full => "14.04",
      major => "14.04"
    }
  },
  family => "Debian",
  hardware => "x86_64",
  name => "Ubuntu",
  release => {
    full => "14.04",
    major => "14.04"
  },
  selinux => {
    enabled => false
  }
}
```

.

```
facter os.release
{
  full => "14.04",
  major => "14.04"
}
```

.

```
facter os.release.major
14.04
```

Comment: Doesn't work with facter 2.2.0

Comment: Doesn't work for me either in facter v2.4.4. Returns a blank line.

Answer (score 1):

That's not what `facter` is supposed to do. If you use it within `puppet` as expected, you can access every fact separately.

To a certain degree, you can work around this if you use `JSON` output:

```
facter --json os | grep major
      "major": "6",
```

and if you have a CLI JSON parser available, everything is possible.

Using [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
facter --json os | jq .os.release.minor
   "6"
```